# Default cache headers for tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat, cache-control, request-headers, response-headers

I am using tomcat 7. When any page/JS file is served I see below headers getting set on browser net panel. Nowhere in code I am setting them.

```
    "Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store"
    "Pragma", "no-cache"
```

Does tomcat set them by default or something else is playing magic here ?

Answer (score -1):

These are the default values considered by the browser. Service can override these response header values